# Cant upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, update-manager, do-release-upgrade, 22.04

Hi i have a vm with Ubuntu 20.04 updated till today ( 12/04/2022), but following the instruction to upgrade it doesnt work.

I followed this tutorial:
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-22-04-lts

But the Software Manager doesnt detect any new version, should detect the 22.04 beta, but also 21.04 and 21.10 at least....but it doesnt.

Also tried update-manager -d

Any help or ideas please.

Edit more info asked by  @user535733:

Output:

```
osboxes@osboxes:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Comprobar si hay una nueva versión de Ubuntu
Las actualizaciones de la versión de desarrollo están 
disponibles desde la última versión soportada
```

In spanish but you can use google translator, but quite self-explanatoy: the updates from development versions avalaible from the latest supported version.

```
osboxes@osboxes:~$ cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
# Default behavior for the release upgrader.

[DEFAULT]
# Default prompting and upgrade behavior, valid options:
#
#  never  - Never check for, or allow upgrading to, a new release.
#  normal - Check to see if a new release is available.  If more than one new
#           release is found, the release upgrader will attempt to upgrade to
#           the supported release that immediately succeeds the
#           currently-running release.
#  lts    - Check to see if a new LTS release is available.  The upgrader
#           will attempt to upgrade to the first LTS release available after
#           the currently-running one.  Note that if this option is used and
#           the currently-running release is not itself an LTS release the
#           upgrader will assume prompt was meant to be normal.
Prompt=normal
```

Comment: Hello. Any question about a version of Ubuntu that does not exist yet is off topic on this site. Sorry.

Comment: I will give you one clue 22.04 does not exist hence no upgrade path.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc. *This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues*   Also don't forget it's still in *testing* with *beta* freeze just *hit* & *beta* release on 31-March-2022

Comment: The upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04 opens **after** the release of Ubuntu 22.04; however the upgrade path from 20.04 (to 22.04) won't be opened until **after** the release of 22.04.1 which is usually ~3 months after the initial release (*for exact date read the release schedule, but do note that refers to the ISO release date, the upgrade opens at earliest the following week*)

Comment: @David  asked this question, because it doesnt work. As i notice in the quetion too ( sorry for my bad english, is not my mother language) is that at least should appear 21.04 and 21.10 ( supposed that i want to wait till august). I want to make some tests as im using a vm. So supposing 22.04 is still beta and so, the ugpgrade should show at least 21.X versions...so something is not working properly

Comment: @guiverc i added a new comment....

Comment: There is no tested, supported upgrade path from 20.04 to 21.04 nor to 21.10. Those releases will NOT appear as options on a 20.04 system. The options for 20.04 are to 20.10 (now closed, since 21.10 has passed End of Life) and to 22.04 (will open in August 2022). Anything else is *unsupported* here: You can do it if you know how, but you are on your own.

Comment: Well then its solved, 20.04 should upgrade to 20.10 but is closed. So you cant jump from 20.04 to 21.04... Are you developer or ubuntu ? But when 22.04 would be released ( should be already be released), then it will be a way to upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 ? Seems logic that many people would need/want to upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 ( stay in LTS releases). Thanks for your explanations.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has two fully QA-tested upgrade paths; (1) to the next release which **was** 20.10 but that ended when 20.10 reached EOL, and (2) to the next LTS **after** Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS is released; it's not been released yet.  Ubuntu CI tests are performed so LTS users can *release-upgrade* to the next non-LTS; so when 20.10 reached EOL upgrade proceeded to 21.04 until it reached EOL, then to 21.10 which is what is available now; but it's CI tested only; not tested by users doing QA though CI testing was done. Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.10 is open & supported, not really ~recommend though.

Comment: You can also upgrade to 22.04 using `-d` for testing purposes but it's not recommended either; I'd wait for the Ubuntu blog article to come out telling you how to do it (ie. use the `-d` I already mentioned) as they'll give caveats on who shouldn't use it, and what users it's safe for; ie. that extra detail from the Ubuntu Release team is why you'd want to wait.  Such an article has been related for prior two LTS releases and may appear in a week, or few weeks. @user535733 made a typo (typed 21.10 instead of 20.10 as I see it) but does know his stuff.

Comment: 22.04.01 was released today, so shortly the upgrade path should open.

Comment: @Mr_road https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-22-04-1-lts-point-release-status-tracking/29102 shows the status, was 2 blocker bugs until recently.. the other is marked in '-proposed' so it'll be open by ~7 days from when it reached -proposed.

Comment: is now safe to make the upgrade or better wait some weeks ? Because as said many people would begin to upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04.1... no =

Comment: The wording is the upgrade opens from 20.04 to 22.04 **after** the release of Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.  The upgrade occurred on Thursday of 11 August, the upgrade doesn't usually occur until the early in the next week which hasn't occurred yet; ie. the Ubuntu Release Team re-assessing the status of it hasn't occurred.  The status tracking document https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-22-04-1-lts-point-release-status-tracking/29102 which showed 1 blocker the day after 11-August-2022 release of 22.04.1, no longer has the blocker today, so it looks good to being open in next few days

Answer (score 11):

Though 22.04 will be released in a few days, **the upgrade path from 20.04 to 22.04 opens later**, currently scheduled for August 2022.

- If you try earlier, you are testing that upgrade path (-d required) to discover the rough edges and file bug reports.
- If you don't wish to be a tester, mark your calendar for early August 2022 and be patient.

If you have decided to become a tester, then observe the instructions on the link you provided to make 22.04 visible to your system:

> First, you need to tell this version of Ubuntu that it’s okay to “see”
> development versions:
>
> ```
> Open Software & Updates tool
> Click the “Updates” tab
> Change “Notify me of a new Ubuntu version” to “For any new version”
> ```

Then `do-release-upgrade -d` should find the new Beta.

Comment: I asked this question, because it doesnt work. As i notice in the quetion too ( sorry for my bad english, is not my mother language) is that at least should appear 21.04 and 21.10 ( supposed that i want to wait till august). I want to make some tests as im using a vm.

Comment: As question explains also tried: update-manager -d. It didnt work either. Thanks

Comment: "It didnt work" is too vague to offer useful advice. SOMETHING must have happened when you used that command. Edit your Question above to include the complete output. Help us to help you. Also check your `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` file.