# Not able to see latest 22.04 LTS UPDATE

Tags: updates, 21.10

Since the official release of the latest **22.04 LTS version**. I am try to update my Destro. But each time I try to check the update the inbuilt updater says that your sysytem is up to date and shows no update.
I tried to check the forced update via usind terminal using the **-d** command but it's showing that '**development version**' of the latest 22.04 is available. Should I update it or not. Please **help**!!

Comment: of it reports as such then your system is up to date. Are you expecting something different?

Comment: But my system is still running on 21.10...

Comment: ah... you tagged 22.04. Have you followed [these steps](https://itsubuntu.com/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-21-10-to-ubuntu-22-04-lts/) to do the upgrade? I've changed the tag.

Comment: Check the current release notes, things were put on pause a few days for some problem.

Comment: Visit https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402113/cant-upgrade-from-20-04-to-22-04, I hope this might help you.